# Google Analytics Error?

Tags: google-analytics

I have Google Analytics on my webpage. The reports show properly as far as I know. But when going through settings I saw this:

[image: Google Analytics Error - Notice The Date]

[(Larger View of Image Here)](http://screencast.com/t/VOIdlPI5H)

Notice the date => I have checked and tracking is on the home page. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you switched to the new GA interface? This appears to be a known bug, according to a response [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=0b1d82756e9b2157&hl=en) and in a bunch of other threads I've run across, going back at least as far as April. You might try trawling around in the [Analytics forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics?hl=en) for a definitive/original statement of that; I haven't managed to track it down.

If you're still getting stats correctly, I wouldn't worry about it too much. That date, immediately before the [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), mysteriously popping up often indicates a glitch.

Comment: I am new to Analytics but I believe I am using the new interface. I will look into the Analytics forum. Thanks for the information =>